# Need help in designing of circuitry. (Power Electronics)

Tags: ldr, 555

The circuit is supposed to detect ambient light and react accordingly.  When there is high illuminance the LED should be dim and when there is low illuminance the LED should be bright.

The transistor is supposed to drive up the current and the NE555 is suppose to control the duty cycle.

The NE555 is supposed to give out high duty cycle when there is low light and give out low duty cycle when there is plenty of light. But the problem is the frequency changes along with it.

Is there a way to change the duty cycle without changing the frequency?

[image]
Circuit design.

Comment: Why is it important to keep the frequency constant?

Comment: @Bob Jacobsen to prevent the led from flickering if that make sense

Comment: How does constant frequency prevent flickering? I'm not sure what you're doing here. I get the feeling a 555 isn't the best tool for the job, at least not in the standard circuit configuration.

Comment: ...also you're calling it a MOSFET, and then labelling it TIP122, which is definitely not a MOSFET. what is it?

Comment: @hearth so any recommendation on how do i fix this

Comment: @Hearth oh that was my mistake sorry...

Comment: @Hearth TIP122 is a Darlington pair NPN transistor. and regarding to constant frequency , I think like make the frequency high enough so that the human eye cant tell that it is flickering

Comment: This system is too complicated for such a simple application. A simple light dependent resistor would be sufficient to do the job: https://in.element14.com/advanced-photonix/norps-12/light-dependent-resistor-1mohm/dp/327700?st=ldr

Comment: Use two timers!

Comment: Tip: use proper schematic symbols for devices such as transistors. It makes it much easier to read and understand and, in this case, it would also make it clear whether the switch is a BJT transistor or MOSFET. If you have errors in your post you should fix them to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this easily by using 2 timers : 
See the figure below.
The second output should be used to drive the MOSFET.

the first timer works in astable mode and sets the frequency which triggers the second timer (on the right) which is used in monostable mode.

You did not specify anything about frequency and duty cycle range, but by inserting your LDR resistor for R4, the duty cycle will change accordingly.

So when there is a lot of light, R4 (your light sensitive resistor) decreases and duty cycle decreases and vice versa.

The values need to tuned to your requirements for frequency and duty cycle range.

[image]